# Get function names from specific string & replace function return values in existing string

Tags: javascript

I have string with slash separated contains function names.

```
e.g.
my_doc/desktop/customer=getCustomer()/getCsvFileName()/controller=getControllerName()
```

Within above string I want only function name i.e. getCustomer(), getControllerName() & getCsvFileName()

in Utilities I have written those functions Like:

```
function getCustomer() { 
 return "Customer1"; 
} 

function getControllerName() { 
 return "myController"; 
} 

function getCsvFileName() { 
 return "userData.csv"; 
}
```

I need to get function names from String using below code:

```
let tokens = [];

for (element of str.split("/"))
  if (element.endsWith("()"))
     tokens.push(element.split("=")[1] ?? element.split("=")[0])

     console.log(tokens);
```

Now I want to call those functions & values return from functions need to replace to existing string.

**So my final string would be:**

```
my_doc/desktop/customer=Customer1/userData.csv/controller=myController
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const fns = {
  getCustomer,
  getControllerName,
  getCsvFileName
};

s = s.replaceAll(/(\w+)\(\)/g, (s, name) => {
  if (!fns[name]) return 'NO_SUCH_FUNCTION';
  return fns[name]();
});
```

Comment: Tried code but not worked for me. getting below error:
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replaceAll')"

Comment: @GarryS Check what you're calling `.replaceAll()` on. It should be `str` in your example. See working example https://jsfiddle.net/h4gzjnck/1